# how to format integers so that it prints spaces before it if there are not three number

Tags: python, formatting, integer

I want to print some sequence of number in a specific format. Like if there are 3 digits it will print the integer but if there are not 3 digits for example if there are two digits or one digit then it will make up spaces. For example:
__3 bench
_55 pencils
675 pens
I wanted to how can I format this. the numbers are always integers.

```
 for key, value in dict.items():
        print(f'{key:} {value}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this by giving `width` to your parameter to print:

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    print (f'{key:>3} {value}')
```

Output:

```
>
  3 bench
 45 pencils
675 pens
```

You can replace 3 with the maximum number of digits you might have in your data or even pass it dynamically :

```
width = 3
for key, value in dict.items():
    print (f'{key:>{width}} {value}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use [`.rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rjust#str.rjust) method after converting `int` to `str`. Consider following example

```
benches = 3
pencils = 55
pens = 675
print(str(benches).rjust(3),"benches")
print(str(pencils).rjust(3),"pencils")
print(str(pens).rjust(3),"pens")
```

output

```
  3 benches
 55 pencils
675 pens
```

Similar methods exists named `.ljust` (justing to left) and `.center`